# Xcode 6 constraints for view in viewController fails

Tags: ios, xcode

I´m pretty new to Xcode and playing around with some techniques.

For testing, i am writing an app where i have a detailViewController with three views within.

As soon as i assign constraints to one of the views the layout gets really strange. No matter if i center horizontally or set border distance, the view seems somehow to vanish and the components within the view are placed somehow.

Any idea what i´m doing wrong?

[image: explample of wrong layout]

Comment: Make you sure you add all the necessary constraints, including width and height.

Comment: I only want them to be fixed distance to left and right

Comment: Yes, but autolayout needs some information about the size AND the position. You can't add some and skip some.

Comment: You seems to have the first view center horizontally with the second view. So the second view seems to be higher than the superview so the first view is center with that. Are you creating the constraints from the storyboard or with code?

Comment: thanks, adding size information did the job. I was confused about the absolute values, but it seems that the size will be adjusted to different devices

Comment: @meligaletiko from storyboard

Comment: You need constraints to the left and right of the screen in all your views. It looks that your view constraints are dependent of each view. I think with a few screenshots of your constraints on the storyboard will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you need to follow these basic rules. Checkout the auto layout [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). Each view from the top of the scene to the bottom should have constraints (also constraints should exist from side-to-side if you want expansion and contraction, or have height/width if those are important to maintain). Most times you will need to have at least four constraints per view. The auto layout errors will not go away until all the views have constraints applied and adhere to the simple rules I mentioned above.